# Run github command in Shiny application

Tags: git, shiny

I have a Shiny application which uses a Python package. This package will be updated frequently and I would like the Shiny app to know the current local version of the package and also try to update it to the last version.

What I am looking is to do it by a sample code (running `git pull` from R) and do it in the background of a Shiny app.

Is this possible? I could not find any sample on the net!

Thanks

Comment: The python package is not part of R or R's packages! it's independent software!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

There is a R library to work around this: `git2r`. Therefore, a start point is:

```
install.packages("git2r")
library(git2r)

## Initialize the repository
repo <- init(path)

## Display a brief summary of the new repository
repo
```

And you can read the documentation from [git2r repository](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r)

I hope that it helps others!